# How to add a topic to a GitHub repo using a GitHub Action?

Tags: github, github-actions

Is there a way to add a topic to a repository using a GitHub Action running within that same repository? The idea is you would push code with the `.github/workflows/add-topic.yml` which would ensure the repo has topic `foo` every time the action runs.

I realize you can do this via the GitHub API, but that requires credentials (i.e. adding a personal access token as a repository secret), which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Not sure if the actions token has sufficient permissions, but the action workflow has a token you can pass to API calls. `${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}`

Comment: Using the Github API inside your workflow seems like the easiest path. Now, you commented that you want to avoid using a PAT. Is it because you'll use it inside an organization, or is it for another reason?

Comment: Good info @jessehouwing! I did not know that was available. I think that addresses my concern.

Comment: @GuiFalourd, right. I'm using topics for metrics across a big team. I don't trust teams will setup secrets to set a topic they don't care about. I need it to "just work".

Comment: I've seen many organizations creating an "organization account" for this kind of operations. Where you could use this organization account PAT in different team repositories (setting it as a secret at the organization level).

Comment: Agree, organization PAT is the way to go. You definitely need PAT to do such operations.

Comment: Right, we set org secrets often, but I want to avoid if possible. It looks like the GITHUB_TOKEN that's automatically injected into Actions does not have enough permissions to change repository topics.